# How many bookcases do you need to get a fortune enchantment (in minecraft)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been trying to get a fortune enchantment for a while and I made plenty of bookshelves and it hasn't been enough.

Comment: I placed 20 bookcases and was able to get a fortune I enchantment but I'm wondering if you can get a fortune enchantment with less bookcases.

Comment: The real answer to the question how many bookshelves are needed at the minimum is very complicated, but using 15 and enchanting on level 30 is almost always the best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Enchanting_table) (emphasis mine):

> To increase the enchantment level, bookshelves can be placed next to the enchanting table while keeping one block of air between them. **To gain access to the previously mentioned level 30 enchantments, a total of 15 bookshelves need to be placed around the enchanting table.**

The maximum level of Fortune<sup>1</sup> is a "Level 30" enchantment, but there is never going to be a guarantee that you will get the Fortune enchantment.

You can limit this by enchanting only picks, shovels and axes, to which Fortune can be applied, meaning that the chance of getting Fortune will be better than enchanting books (which can have any enchantment applied).

<sup>1. Fortune 1 and 2 can be accessed at lower levels below the maximum; but for simplicity's sake I have only included the Requirements for Fortune 3. There is a lot of calculations and variables that go into selecting an Enchantment, let alone a specific one. See [Enchanting Mechanics](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting_mechanics) for more information</sup>

Comment: But he asked how many bookshelves are required to get fortune, he didn't ask how to increase enchantment levels

Comment: @Howdoi.... Fortune is a level 30 enchantment, Wich requires 15 bookshelves. I'm not sure where you believe you got that I mentioned anything about increasing enchantment levels though?

Comment: Any source on Fortune being a level 30 enchantment? 'cause [the wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Enchanting/Levels) gives 15 for Fortune 1, 24 for Fortune 2, and 33 for Fortune 3. Meaning slot 3, on gold tool, has a chance to add Fortune 1 to a golden pickaxe even without any bookshelves.

Comment: @SF. I have clarified

Answer (score 0):

One other way to get a fortune 3 enchantment is by enchanting books in the enchantment table until you get 3 fortune 1 books then combine all 3 of the fortune 1 books in a anvil to get a fortune 3 enchanted book then add it to a item.

Comment: You need 4 fortune I book to make a fortune 3 book.